# How to fix sporadic read timeout and service unavailable error in Azure Cosmos Emulator (Linux) running in docker?

Tags: java, linux, azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I am running  Linux cosmos emulator with below configurations (as per official Microsoft documention) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 ( I tried 18.04 as well)

```
ipaddr="`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1`"
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
sudo docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254  -m 4g --cpus=2.0 --name=test-linux-emulator -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

Also adding the certificate to Java keystore as per the official document.

**what I am doing?**
I am running Unit testing connecting to Emulator of simple CRUD operation with atmost 1 or 2 items.
Each test will create a container and delete the container.
My Machine configuration is 4 core and 16 GB memory.
I am running Junit in spring boot.

**Whats happening?**
Sporadically unit test cases are failing with read timeout or service unavailable error. I have observed in the Emulator UI, that databases disappear sometime but emulator is always up and running.

**Note:** The same is working fine when I run cosmos DB Emulator in windows 10 (both exe and as a docker container).

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What could be the issue when running with Linux ?
2. Is it ok to delete cosmos container(table) and create again for each test cases?

Any suggestion for the issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. What could be the issue when running with Linux?

Answer: There should not be any problem running Cosmos Emulator (Linux) on Linux. Infect this could be very suitable since both are referring for same OS.

2. Is it ok to delete container and create again for each test cases?

Answer: Seems this is not appropriate to delete and create container for each test case.

Would suggest you to use the same container for all unit testing If you still want to perform the same thing make sure to stop the container before deleting it because directly deleting the container might docker daemon throws an error. We must first stop the container and delete it.

Reference: https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/docker-container-lifecycle-management/

Comment: Are you referring to cosmos DB container (tables) ? To be clear I have updated the cosmos DB container in the question.

Comment: the above answer is general and for all type of container.

Comment: Sorry, I think little misunderstanding.. in cosmos DB, the tables are called containers for sql. So I am referring to tables (containers) inside Cosmos DB.

Comment: May i know what is the configuration of your window machine where it is working fine ?

Comment: The configuration of windows machine is same.. 4 core and 16 GB Memory

Comment: Would request you to reach out to azure support :https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview

Comment: Hello @sub , If my answer and comment is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you